# Is there a way to force windows to become smaller?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, windows

Many windows in gnome will not allow the window to be shrunk beyond a certain size. Is there a way to disable this to allow these windows to be made even smaller?

Comment: This depends on the application. If the application has set a minimum width and/or height, you can't make the window smaller than this.

Comment: Are you using the maximum resolution of the screen? Which applications are causing problems for you? What kind of problems? Maybe there is a workaround.